# Fine-tuning a model from an existing checkpoint with TensorFlow-Slim

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow, inception

I'm trying to retrain the final layer of a pretrained model with a new image dataset using **TensorFlow-Slim**.

Lets say I want to fine-tuning inception-v3 on flowers dataset. Inception_v3 was trained on ImageNet with 1000 class labels, but the flowers dataset only have 5 classes. Since the dataset is quite small we will only train the new layers.

An example at [official tf github page](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/slim#fine-tuning-a-model-from-an-existing-checkpoint) shows how to do it:

```
$ DATASET_DIR=/tmp/flowers
$ TRAIN_DIR=/tmp/flowers-models/inception_v3
$ CHECKPOINT_PATH=/tmp/my_checkpoints/inception_v3.ckpt
$ python train_image_classifier.py \
    --train_dir=${TRAIN_DIR} \
    --dataset_dir=${DATASET_DIR} \
    --dataset_name=flowers \
    --dataset_split_name=train \
    --model_name=inception_v3 \
    --checkpoint_path=${CHECKPOINT_PATH} \
    --checkpoint_exclude_scopes=InceptionV3/Logits,InceptionV3/AuxLogits/Logits \
    --trainable_scopes=InceptionV3/Logits,InceptionV3/AuxLogits/Logits
```

---

I couldn't fully understand all the parameters in the above code:

`train_dir` = **?**

`dataset_dir` = new dataset directory location

`dataset_name` = name of the dataset (but why **?** )

`dataset_split_name` = **?**

`model_name` = name of the model on which we want to train

`checkpoint_path` = path to the model checkpoint

`checkpoint_exclude_scopes` = **?**

`trainable_scopes` = **?**

---

**Help me figure out what these parameter means and correct me if I'm wrong about any of the parameter?**

Note: I'm aware that we can retrain inception_v3 with a method mentioned at [official tensorflow website](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/image_retraining) but I want to do the same with tensorflow-slim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all information you need from the [source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/slim/train_image_classifier.py).

- train_dir: Directory where checkpoints and event logs are written to. (default: /tmp/tfmodel/)
- dataset_dir: The directory where the dataset files are stored.
- dataset_name: The name of the dataset to load. (default: imagenet)
- dataset_split_name: The name of the train/test split. (default: train)
- model_name: The name of the architecture to train. (default: inception_v3)
- checkpoint_path: The path to a checkpoint from which to fine-tune.
- checkpoint_exclude_scopes: Comma-separated list of scopes of variables to exclude when restoring from a checkpoint.
- trainable_scopes: Comma-separated list of scopes to filter the set of variables to train. By default, None would train all the variables.

Comment: If I'm using a custom dataset, why should I give `dataset_name`? Is that `train_dir`  works just like:`file_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('/path/to/logs', sess.graph)` collecting event logs. How do you find these list of scopes of variables to  be exclude or  list of scopes to filter the set of variables to train without interrupting the model?

Comment: After reading the source code, I found out `train_image_classifier.py` script didn't provides custom dataset support. Dataset is restricted [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/slim/train_image_classifier.py#L414) and [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/slim/datasets/dataset_factory.py#L53). If you insist fine-tuning with tf-slim, maybe you need to implement the dataset part yourself.

Comment: But the example in the question shows how to fine tune  pretrained inception model on imagenet, with custom dataset flower.

Comment: `flowers` is actually a built-in dataset. Checkout https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/slim/datasets/flowers.py

Comment: Do you have any tips that will help me implement the dataset part myself?

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not a tf-slim user :-(

Comment: How to change the final layer classes ? The tutorial hasn't give much on that.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what @Icyblade suggested by citing the source code, I'd like to add a few things.

- `dataset_name` is an option that tells slim how to read the TFRecords located in the `dataset_dir` folder.
  The default value `imagenet` means that the TFRecords have to have this format: `train-00146-of-00168.tfrecord` or `validation-00003-of-00019.tfrecord`.
  The value `flowers` means that slim expects the TFRecords to have the form `flowers_train_00146-of-00168.tfrecord` or `flowers_validation_00003-of-00019.tfrecord`. This peculiar way of formatting the tfrecords is defined [here in the source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/546fd48ecb70635e5b086143c252649b217df59d/slim/datasets/download_and_convert_flowers.py#L102).
  Different sample datasets have different formatting rules, e.g. [here you can see cifar10](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/546fd48ecb70635e5b086143c252649b217df59d/slim/datasets/download_and_convert_cifar10.py#L118).
- Moreover, `dataset_split_name` tells the converter how to name the
  TFRecords files. For the flowers dataset they are `train` and
  `validation`, for cifar10 they are `train` and `test`, etc.
- About `checkpoint_exclude_scopes` and `trainable_scopes`, to make a
  long story short, these commands tell the training algorithm to
  remove the final two layers of the network from the last checkpoint
  available (either passed by the `checkpoint_path` option or read from
  the folder specified in `train_dir`), and make it retrain the CNN on
  them, but using the images you provide inside the TFRecords file.
  Thus, using these options means to perform a *retrain* -or, as the
  slim devs call it in the README, a *fine-tuning* from an existing
  checkpoint (link in the comments)- of a CNN on another set of images.

To give you an hint about how to build your own TFRecord converter/creator, I'd suggest to base it on the download_and_convert_flowers.py script, since the input dataset is regular, with the images divided in categories, where each category is a single folder.
Moreover, I'd extend it by adding the option to read input png images (the flowers pictures are only jpg, and thus the script doesn't need this conversion, but your future dataset may). Start by de-assembling it piece by piece and remove the hard-coded information related to the flowers dataset, to make it less specific.

Comment: [Fine tuning a model from an existing checkpoint](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/546fd48ecb70635e5b086143c252649b217df59d/slim/#fine-tuning-a-model-from-an-existing-checkpoint). (Unfortunately I have not enough reputation so far to post more than two links in an answer). Best luck!

Comment: [Map of the inception-v3 model](https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-TMOLlkJBxms/Vt3HQXpE2cI/AAAAAAAAA8E/7X7XRFOY6Xo/s1600/image03.png): the AuxLogits and Logits levels we remove when retraining/fine-tuning are those two blocks made up of 5 operations, that end with a softmax (red brick).